# PHP load txt file as an array

Tags: php, arrays, text, file-get-contents

I have a text file (id.txt) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 13
    [13] => 15
    [14] => 16
    [15] => 101
)
```

How can I load this text file as an array in PHP? I think I'd have to use `file_get_contents()` but I don't know how to use it and allow PHP to read it as an array.

Comment: That's a bad way to store data and now you're paying for it

Comment: Why do you have an array saved like that, you should save array to files with json_encode for example and then read with json_decode

Comment: try to store as json array. Then you can easily get back your actual array.

Comment: You're welcome: https://eval.in/83186

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("/\[(\d+)\] => (\d+)/",file_get_contents('id.txt'), $matches);
var_dump($matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your answer for this question is probably something like what @Joni Salmi suggested.

But you really should store your array as a json string.

```
$jsonString = json_encode($my_array);
writeToFile($my_array);

/* then, to read: */
$storedJsonString = file_get_contents($file);
$myArray = json_decode($storedJsonString);
```